# How to access data in a nested List in c# reportviewer?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, .net-3.5, reportviewer

I have a Business Object which contains a `DataTable` among other properties. I pass a `List<>` of this object as my report `DataSource`.

In my report I have a `List` that display some properties and a nested `List` in which I want to show the rows of the current object `DataTable`, but i can't seem to get the `Expression` for getting the values to work, i only get an `#Error` displaying in the report.

I have also set the child `List` `DataElementName` and `DataInstanceName` with no luck.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally decided to go in another way, making a subreport, and exchanging the original `DataTable` for a another `List<>` of a new Businees Object.

CodeSample can be found in [gotreportviewer](http://gotreportviewer.com/objectdatasources/index.html) in the nested objects section.